# Table data continuous changing according to Array items in Metro app?

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a metro application,in which am trying to display table data continuously changing like data changing on tiles in windows 8 start-up screen.Actually here I have an Array contains many items and my table need to display those item-description.For every 5 secs I need to change item-description on my table, what should I do for my scenario?Can anyone give me advice..
Thank you.

Comment: You want to have a view of the list change? (Eg pick a new item from the list to display? Or you have a view already, and you want to change the description and have it updated in the UI?

Comment: @DominicHopton , Actually I have Json data related to many users,I want to change user-data for every 5 secs or Pick a new item from the list to display.

Comment: @DominicHopton ,I have a datasource which contains service data related many users.I want to display those data on a Single listview-item and it need to change for every 5 secs.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using databinding to accomplish this task.

Replacing simple arrays with a WinJS.Binding.List (which will notify the ListView about new or removed items) and using either the WinJS.Binding.mixin or WinJS.Binding.as to make the items themselves observable (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229801.aspx).

This way you can bind elements in your ListView itemtemplate to properties of your domain model, making the UI update itself as soon as you change something in the model.